# Sitecore Search API not searching List of Guids Unsupported expression node type

Tags: solr, content-search, search-facet

I have created an index field called "facetCategory".

```
 public class IndexResultModel : SearchResultItem
    {
        [IndexField("facetcategory_sm")]
        public IList<Guid> FacetCategory { get; set; }
     }
```

I am using search API and passing comma seperated guids to search.I am using the following code to retirve the results where FacetCategory contains list of Guids.

```
 try
            {
            var query = context.GetQueryable<IndexResultModel >();
            var containsQuery = PredicateBuilder.True<IndexResultModel >();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filters))
            {
                var facets = filters.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                foreach (string facet in facets)
                {
                    containsQuery = containsQuery.Or(item => item.FacetCategory.Contains(new Guid(facet)));
                }
                //join the predicate and the containsQuery
                predicate = predicate.And(containsQuery);
            }
            query = query.Where(predicate);
            if (latitude != 0 && longitude != 0)
            {
                query = query.WithinRadius(i => i.GeoLoc, latitude, longitude, distance).OrderByNearest();
            }
            if (currentPage > 0 && resultPerPage > 0)
            {
                Results = query.Skip((currentPage - 1) * currentPage).Take(resultPerPage).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                Results = query.ToList();
            }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
```

I am getting an error because of adding the below code to search code

```
containsQuery = containsQuery.Or(item => item.FacetCategory.Contains(new Guid(facet)));
```

The error says "**Unsupported expression node type: MemberAccess within type constructor parameter**".
I have tried the other index fields which are string or integer and it works fine but because facetcategory_sm type is IList, it can not query contains guids.

here is screenshot of the field being indexed in Solr

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot how the list of guid appears on the solr when you query it directly on the solr server?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya I have added the screenshot of the fields being indexed in Solr in the post.

Comment: Can you try to put it as `List<string>` instead of `IList<Guid>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create your Guid variable first before trying to filter FacetCategory on it, Something like:

```
Guid facetGuid = new Guid(facet);
containsQuery = containsQuery.Or(item => item.FacetCategory.Contains(facetGuid))
```